# How to perform moderator analysis in ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: regression, interaction, spss, ordinal-data

How to perform moderator analysis in ordinal logistic regression using SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

A basic assessment of whether one variable moderates the relationship between another variable and a dependent variable is usually carried out by fitting a model with both of those variables as predictors, plus their interaction, and assessing the interaction term. This is done in the same way in the Ordinal Regression (or PLUM for the syntax procedure name) procedure in SPSS. So if you're interested in predicting Y with X, and want to know if Z moderates any relationship, specify Y as the dependent variable, X and Z as either factors or covariates, depending on what kind of variables they are (factors are categorical, covariates are what's referred to as scale in the program, often assumed continuous), then click on the Location button. In that dialog, click Custom to define a custom model rather than a default main-effects model, and include both main effects and the interaction.

Comment: Would you have an article to reference this response? I have found it very useful for my thesis project.